# Best way to get latest git code with Docker image restart?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Between each Docker image build, the only thing that change is the source code. Right now, I rebuild the image every time, then push to the server. This operation takes time.

What is the best practice to update the code on the server? I was thinking about running some commands every time the Docker restart, like this:

```
RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org/{user}/{repo}
```

Is it a good practice? The source code would then be on the host; is it secure?

Here is my current Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm git
RUN npm install -g bower
RUN ln /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

# Add the current working folder as a mapped folder
ADD app.js /opt/myapp/app.js
ADD dist /opt/myapp/dist
ADD package.json /opt/myapp/package.json
ADD bower.json /opt/myapp/bower.json

# Set the current working directory to the new mapped folder.
WORKDIR /opt/myapp

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install
RUN bower install --allow-root --config.interactive=false

# Expose the node.js port to the Docker host.
EXPOSE 3005

# This is the stock express binary to start the app.
CMD [ "node", "app.js"]
```

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind to speed things up is that you could move the npm and bowerinstallation before the ADD. This way docker would avoid installing npm and bower every time. What you are adding with ADD is your application, am I correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, I am adding my application code. I will try and let you know. However, as there is a package.json and bower.json in my project, this is why I am doing npm install and bower install.

Comment: You are right. Anyway, you can do it in this order: add package.json, npm install, add bower.json, bower install and as last step add app.js and dist. That way docker will re-excute the installations only when something changes.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. npm and bower always install the packages each time.

Comment: I use my dev setup with Docker container keeping the git code cloned and updated on my Host OS and regularly: updating, rebasing and bulding the code on the host OS itself. To test the changes I start a container with a shared volume mount my binaries and/or source into the container for testing. In that way you dont need to rebuild or commit the container for changes or git updates.

Comment: I though ADD always invalidated the cache, but apparently not (like https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/880#issuecomment-47100711)

Comment: @askb, how do you update the code on the host after each git push ?

Comment: This is the reason you have shared volume of the git code base on the host OS. You build it on the host while you only test it with in the docker container. `git  push | fetch | updates` are all handled on the host OS.

Comment: Ok I understand. In my case, I don't have access to the host. However, I could easily set up an other Docker image which would fetch the latest code then share it through the shared volume. I like this idea.

Answer (score 3):

I have a good practice recently, because I just made a docker last week: the source code hosted on github, testing use CircleCI, auto-build on DockerHub, auto-deploy on Tutum.co, and at last, run by my own server(some of them I have never logined)

every time I push code to github, github will send notification to Tutum by webhook. then Tutum will get the source code, start building and testing my new docker image. if test passed,  image will be pushed to my private registry. then tutum will send re-deploy notification to my docker service, my docker will pull the new image, terminate the old container, relaunch new container with the latest image for me.

all above is totally automaticly. everything will happen after I run a "git push" command.

personally I use tutum very heavy, so I recommand you to read a article of Tutum Automated Build: https://support.tutum.co/support/solutions/articles/5000638474-automated-builds

also, you could have a look of my docker, I use almose everything I could find to this tiny toy project(CI/CD). :)
https://github.com/zixia/docker-simple-mail-forwarder

Comment: Thanks. It's the kind of solution I was looking for. A bit more step-by-step explanations would have help me to reproduce it fast... But still, I give you +1 !

Comment: haha, thanks. this is my first answer on stackoverflow, and you helped me got my first reputatoin score! :D I suggest you to get a step-by-step study from tutum automated builds. it's very easy to follow all of those.

Comment: @zixia I'm intrigued by your setup. Where does CircleCI sit within it? Github -> CircleCI -> Dockerhub -> Tutum? You know that Tutum can handle docker builds now, so you can deprecate the Dockerhub step?

Comment: @Scotty yes, you are right: some part of steps are redundancy. My main procedure is: Github -> Tutum Repository Auto-build(Test&Push) -> Tutum Auto Deploy -> Each of my Server  get updated. I use CircleCI to: 1. show a "passed" badge on github readme. 2. if test failed, email me. CircleCI could also build & push images, but that will need more work by myself. I use Docker Hub to auto-build and publish my image(by github webhook), without test (yet). use circleci to push docker hub image which is passed the test would be better.

Comment: @zixia, What is the exact repository for the auto-build and CircleCi? Like tutum/[service_name] .

Comment: @JLavoie you mean in my case? it's tutum.co/zixia/simple-mail-forwarder:latest (but i think its private) and https://circleci.com/gh/zixia/docker-simple-mail-forwarder (public). other public links like https://github.com/zixia/docker-simple-mail-forwarder and https://hub.docker.com/r/zixia/simple-mail-forwarder .

Comment: how about mark my answer as the selected answer? :)